# JAXB/MOXy: How to un-/marshall a field containing a scalar or list of scalars

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I have a set of properties and each value of a single property is either a scalar (String, Integer, ...) or a collection of scalars (Collection, Collection, ...). Here is an XML document serving as as an example:

```
<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:java="http://java.oracle.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <property name="test#1" xsi:type="xs:int">1</property>
    <property name="test#2" xsi:type="java:int[]">
        <value xsi:type="xs:int">1</value>
        <value xsi:type="xs:int">2</value>
        <value xsi:type="xs:int">3</value>
    <value xsi:type="xs:int">4</value>
    </property>
</properties>
```

This is the class I would like to use, but I have no idea how to tag the value field correctly to consume and produce this structure. It must contain the parsed content of the property element in the form of a scalar or a list of scalars. The datatype is present as attribute value.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "property")
public class Property {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    protected String name;
    @???
    protected Object value;
}
```

Using two fields `protected Object scalar` and `protected List<Object> list`, one tagged with `@XmlValue`, the other with `@XmlElement(name = "value")` is not working.

Has anybody an idea?

## UPDATE 1

I tagged `Property` as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "property")
public class Property {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    protected String name;
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Test2Adapter.class)
    @XmlPath(".")
    protected Object value;
}
```

I have partly implemented the following Adapter class

```
public class Test2Adapter extends XmlAdapter<AdaptedValue, Object> {

@Override
public Object unmarshal(AdaptedValue v) throws Exception {
    if (v instanceof Scalar) {
    return ((Scalar) v).value;
    }
    if (v instanceof Complex) {
        return ((Complex) v).value;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public AdaptedValue marshal(Object v) throws Exception {
    if (v instanceof String) {
    Scalar s = new Scalar();
    s.value = v;

    return s;
    }
if (v instanceof Collection) {
    Complex c = new Complex();
    c.value = (Collection<? extends Object>) v;

    return c;
}
return null;
}
```

**AdaptedValue:**

```
@XmlSeeAlso({ Scalar.class, Complex.class })
public abstract class AdaptedValue {
}
```

**Scalar:**

```
public class Scalar extends AdaptedValue {

    @XmlValue
    public Object value;

}
```

**Complex :**

```
public class Complex extends AdaptedValue {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "xsi:type")
    public String type;

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    public Collection<? extends Object> value   
}
```

Everything is marshalled correctly, but unmarshalling does not work. I get the following exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-43] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Missing class for indicator field value [xs:string] of type[class java.lang.String].
Descriptor:
XMLDescriptor(com.materna.osgi.service.cm.rest.resource.representation.Test2Adapter$AdaptedValue --> [])]
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:190)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you need something called XmlJavaTypeAdapter. I used this a long time ago and I do not have my code handy right now, but please take a look at the link and if you are still stuck then do give me a shout.

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/04/xmladapter_in_j.html

In the comments section of the above post, "pomcompot" mentions using wrapper for the List/Collection. I remember using the wrapper class and it worked.

http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/jaxb-annotations.xtp#XmlJavaTypeAdapter